# Conditional expectation of the beta distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I am having difficult time figuring the answer to the following problem.

> Let $X_i \sim Beta(1, \alpha) $ for some $i = 1, \ldots , n$ and $\alpha > 0$. Find the following expectation: $$ E\left [ \log (1 - X_1) \Bigg \vert \prod_1^n (1 - X_i) \right]$$

I have tried writing this out as an integral, but I quickly get stuck with complicated expressions. Is there an easier way to see the result?

Comment: Indeed, I am going to make the edit.

Comment: Note that $E\left[\ln(1-X_1)\mid \prod_{i=1}^n (1-X_i)=t\right]=E\left[\ln (1-X_1)\mid \sum_{i=1}^n \ln(1-X_i)=\ln t\right]$ for any $t\in (0,1)$. Assuming $X_i$'s are i.i.d, the answer follows.